# In Django how to render hello.html in base.html?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am new to django and I misunderstand how to use templates.

I have a a file called base.html which I see as a parent to hello.html.

In hello.html I have this syntax:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block hello %}
<h1>hello</h1>
I should see this template. This is the hello.html template.
{% endblock %}
```

In base.html I have this syntax:

```
{% block hello %}{% endblock %}
```

It is my understanding that django should render hello.html inside of base.html

When I deploy my two html files, django ignores my syntax.

Question: How to render hello.html in base.html?

The files are visible inside of github:

https://github.com/danbikle/sof1231/blob/master/hello/templates/base.html

https://github.com/danbikle/sof1231/blob/master/hello/templates/hello.html

Also I deployed them to heroku with these commands:

```
heroku create sof1231
git push heroku master
```

You can see base.html deployed to https://sof1231.herokuapp.com

Again,
How to render hello.html in base.html?

Comment: Show us your views code on how do you render the template?

Comment: I was following this doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#templates which I think has wrong syntax in it. The answer below works well for me.

Comment: @user3676943: I'm not sure that `include` is the way to go. There's nothing wrong with the templates that you show, so there might be a problem with the way that you are rendering them. For that reason you should add your view code (as already suggested by Shang Wang) so this can be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a template in another template, you use [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

**base.html**

```
{% include 'hello.html' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your templates are designed to work with inheritance, and there is nothing wrong with the simplified templates that you show in your question (I didn't check those on github).

I think that your problem *might* be caused by your view rendering the `base.html` template, when it should instead be rendering the `hello.html` template. You should add your view code to your question so that this can be verified. Your view code should be something like this, which renders the child template `hello.html`:

```
def hello(request):
    template_variables = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    return render(request, 'hello.html', template_variables)
```

---

Another answer (which you have accepted) recommends using `include`. I don't think that `include` is the correct approach.

There is a difference between inheriting from a base template and simple inclusion of content from another file. One important benefit of template inheritance is that you can add common content (e.g. menu, side bars, footers, etc.) to a "base" template and then inherit from that base in child templates without duplicating the common content for each page. Another benefit is that the child templates can override content in the base templates, e.g. `<title>`. This allows you to markup areas of your layout in the base template (using `block`) and then override the content of the block with other content. This is not possible with a simple `include`.